# HikariCP DataSourceProperties in YML file

Tags: java, postgresql, google-app-engine, hikaricp

I'm using Micronaut and trying to implement Hikari for connection to a PostgresSQL database. I've got it working on a local connection using a yml configuration

```
datasources:
  default:
    jdbcUrl: "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:3306/playland"
    username: "user"
    password: "password"
```

and it works great. The problem is, when I deploy it to App Engine, I need to use the following. I would prefer (I think) to add it to the yml configuration if possible but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
// For Java users, the Cloud SQL JDBC Socket Factory can provide authenticated connections.
// See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory for details.
config.addDataSourceProperty("socketFactory", "com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory");
config.addDataSourceProperty("cloudSqlInstance", CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME);
```

I've made it work using a config as explained in the tutorial but I'm running into issues incorporating the datasourceproperties into the yml configuration. I tried this based on another SO answer:

```
datasources:
  default:
    jdbcUrl: "jdbc:postgresql:///playland"
    username: "user"
    password: "password"
    hikari:
      data-source-properties:
        socketFactory: "com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory"
        cloudSqlInstance: "project:region:instance"
```

But it didn't work. Is there a way to add it or no?

Comment: Try to set them without hikari.data-source-properties (like `datasources.default.socketFactory` and so on. Prefix `hikari` is for spring boot datasource autoconfiguration.

Comment: Pretty sure I tried that but I can give it another shot

Comment: Yep, doesn't work.

Comment: have you also tried only without `hikari.` prefix? Like `datasources.default.data-source-properties.socketFactory` ?

Comment: Just tried. Also tried dataSourceProperties just in case (w/o the hikari prefix)...does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the **full JDBC URL** instead:

```
jdbc:postgresql:///<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory&user=<POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME>&password=<POSTGRESQL_USER_PASSWORD>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

[Cloud SQL Socket Factory for JDBC drivers](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory)